# What type should I use for filename strings in C for iOS project?

Tags: objective-c, c, string

I have a C library that I'm using from within an iOS Objective-C program. One of the functions of my C library reads in and processes data from a file. Currently that function looks something like this

```
internalType* parseFile(const char* filename);
```

Is passing in a char* for the filename like this safe on iOS or am I shooting myself in the foot with unicode?  Is there a preferred practice here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely UTF-8. To be safe, you should use `CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation` for URLs and `-[NSString fileSystemRepresentation]` for paths.

Answer (score 2):

Yes... `const char *` should work fine for C things, especially as they match the C functions you're likely to call into, such as [`fopen`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/fopen.3.html).

If your files are likely to have wacky non-Ascii filenames though, all bets are off.  :-)  You would be safer doing the Objective C calls which take `NSURL`'s or `NSString` objects.

Comment: So I can call it thus: `parseFile([filename cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]));` ?

Comment: Yes, that should work.  But again, if you have wacky non-ASCII characters in the filename, expect unexpected (and bad) behavior.

Comment: That's exactly my fear. I'm hoping that iOS won't let that happen (this will be a file within the application bundle)

Comment: If it's a file within your application bundle (that gets code signed, and only you get to modify or change), then I'd say you are safe.